# XAML individual scrolling on items in a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a situation where I want to see a queue of items related to another list.  I want to arrange the parent items vertically and the child items horizontally.  So Far I have the following:

Parent:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listResources" ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ResourceControl x:Name="resources" thisResource="{Binding Path=.}" Margin="2"></local:ResourceControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

My Child items:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel 
                            Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                
                            Margin="3">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" x:Name="labelResourceName" Text="{Binding ResourceName}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="listOperations" ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
            <DataTemplate>                                                     
                    <local:OperationControl x:Name="operations" thisOperation="{Binding Path=.}" Margin="2" ></local:OperationControl>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This works relatively well and gives me my child items listed horizontally as I want them to be.  The problem is that I need to be able to scroll the child items individually.  As it is written currently I have the ability to scroll horizontally, but all of the child items scroll together.

I have attempted to wrap the parent listbox inside a  but that did not seem to do it either.

How can I get the items inside of the listbox to scroll individually instead of all together as a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue.  The problem was that I had not defined a width for the listboxes.  Once I added widths to the controls the scrolling worked properly.